# How to plot a surface defined by parts in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have two surfaces with different range. I'm trying to connect them. The surfaces are a cylindrical and a hyperboloid. When I do

```
gnuplot> splot [-pi:pi][-5:0] 7*cos(u), 7*sin(u), v
gnuplot> replot [-pi:pi][0:1.5] 7*cos(u)*cosh(v), 7*sin(u)*cosh(v), 6*sinh(v)
gnuplot>
```

I only see the graph with the last range, but I want the resultant surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current gnuplot (version 5.2) the sampling ranges use coordinates u and v, which are distinct from the axis ranges for x and y.  To plot multiple surfaces with different ranges you must give the u and v ranges separately for each surface. See for example the 9th plot of the "sampling.dem" demo. An on-line copy is at
    http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_cvs/sampling.html

The commands to generate this plot are

```
set xrange [1:100]
set yrange [1:100]
set urange [0:100]
set vrange [70:90]

splot '++' using 1:2:($1*25.*sin($2/10)), \
      [u=30:70][v=0:50] '++' using 1:2:(u*v), \
      [u=40:80][v=30:60] '++' using (u):(v):(u*sqrt(v)) lt 4, \
      [u=1:100][v=500:1000] '++' using (90):(u):(v) lt 6
```

Note that parametric mode is *not* used.